# matplotlib plt.figsize() parameters not working with pandas DataFrame plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a program that is analyzing a dataset from a pandas dataframe.

The following is part of the program and it works perfectly:

```
selected_columns = ['cap-color', 'gill-color', 'veil-color', 'spore-print-color']
for col in selected_columns:
    x = X[col].value_counts()
    x_vals = x.values.tolist()
    cap_color_list = ['brown', 'gray', 'red', 'yellow', 'white', 'buff', 'pink', 'cinnamon', 'green', 'purple']
    gill_color_list = ['buff', 'pink', 'white', 'brown', 'gray', 'chocolate', 'purple', 'black', 'red', 'yellow', 'orange', 'green']
    veil_color_list = ['white', 'brown', 'orange', 'yellow']
    spore_print_color_list = ['white', 'brown', 'black', 'chocolate', 'green', 'purple', 'orange', 'buff', 'yellow']
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), facecolor='0.9')
    x.plot(kind='bar', width=0.7, color='lightgreen', edgecolor='darkgreen')
    if col == 'cap-color':
        plt.xticks([i for i in range(len(x))], cap_color_list, rotation=0)
        plt.title('cap-color', fontsize=15, color='darkred', weight='bold')
    if col == 'gill-color':
        plt.xticks([i for i in range(len(x))], gill_color_list, rotation=0)
        plt.title('gill-color', fontsize=15, color='darkred', weight='bold')
    if col == 'veil-color':
        plt.xticks([i for i in range(len(x))], veil_color_list, rotation=0)
        plt.title('veil-color', fontsize=15, color='darkred', weight='bold')
    if col == 'spore-print-color':
        plt.xticks([i for i in range(len(x))], spore_print_color_list, rotation=0)
        plt.title('spore-print-color', fontsize=15, color='darkred', weight='bold')
    for i, number in enumerate(x_vals):
        plt.text(x=i, y=number, s=str(number), horizontalalignment='center', fontsize=10, weight='bold')

    plt.xlabel("Color", size=16, labelpad=8, color='darkred')
    plt.ylabel("Count", size=16, labelpad=8, color='darkred')
    plt.show()
```

Sample output (just one, not all four):
[image]

Note how the light grey face color is applied.

Later in the program I have this block of code:

```
# plt.clf()
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), facecolor='0.9')
TEMP.plot(kind='bar', width=0.9)
for i, number in enumerate(TEMP['e']):
    plt.text(x=i - 0.25, y=number + 0.9, horizontalalignment='center', s=round(number, 2), fontsize=8, weight='bold')
for i, number in enumerate(TEMP['p']):
    plt.text(x=i + 0.22, y=number + 0.9, horizontalalignment='center', s=round(number, 2), fontsize=8, weight='bold')
plt.xticks([i for i in range(6)], population, rotation=0)
plt.title('Population', fontsize=15, color='darkred', weight='bold')
# plt.ylim(top=3000)
plt.xlabel("Population Type", size=16, labelpad=8, color='darkred')
plt.ylabel("Count", size=16, labelpad=8, color='darkred')
plt.show()
```

I get this result:

[image]

This entire line does nothing:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), facecolor='0.9')
```

No matter what I change the figsize values to, nothing changes.  The facecolor='0.9' is also
not being applied.

Everything else about the second bar chart is correct.

*Why am I unable to control the figsize and facecolor in the second bar chart?*

The second bar chart is being created from this temp df:

```
print('*' * 26)
TEMP = df.groupby('class')['population'].value_counts().unstack(level=1).fillna(0).T.sort_values('e', ascending=False)
TEMP = TEMP.astype(int)
print(TEMP)
print('*' * 26, '\n')
```

Output:

```
**************************
class          e     p
population            
v           1192  2848
y           1064   648
s            880   368
n            400     0
a            384     0
c            288    52
**************************
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) returns an `Axes`, and has a `figsize` parameter.
- This option won't work if `facecolor` is used as a parameter inside the `DataFrame.plot`

```py
ax = x.plot(kind='bar', width=0.7, color='lightgreen', edgecolor='darkgreen', figsize=(8, 6))

ax = TEMP.plot(kind='bar', width=0.9, figsize=(8, 6))
```

- If `facecolor` is required, use this implementation.

```py
fig, axe = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6), facecolor='0.9')
x.plot(kind='bar', width=0.7, color='lightgreen', edgecolor='darkgreen', ax=axe)

fig, axe = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6), facecolor='0.9')
TEMP.plot(kind='bar', width=0.9, ax=axe)
```

Comment: @MarkS i haven't used facecolor, but i did test it and had the same thing happen. I'd used the second option if you need to use facecolor.